# mysql query to find every occurrence of a non-ascii character in a table column and replace it with its HTML equivalent

Tags: sql, mysql, non-ascii-characters

I have a column that contains HTML strings and has characters like ® and ™ in it. I want to replace all such characters with their HTML equivalent. Is this possible?

Comment: It should be possible (using Regexp) but... we have 21st century and Unicode is pretty well supported (even by PHP) so why do you want to do such horrible thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743070/removing-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-using-python-django

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with multiple nested REPLACE function calls http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace .

```
REPLACE("nonascii2", "&htmlnonascii2", REPLACE("nonascii1", "&htmlnonascii1", "mystring"))
```