# How can I remove non-ASCII characters but leave periods and spaces?

Tags: python, text, unicode, filter, ascii

I'm working with a .txt file. I want a string of the text from the file with no non-ASCII characters. However, I want to leave spaces and periods. At present, I'm stripping those too. Here's the code:

```
def onlyascii(char):
    if ord(char) < 48 or ord(char) > 127: return ''
    else: return char

def get_my_string(file_path):
    f=open(file_path,'r')
    data=f.read()
    f.close()
    filtered_data=filter(onlyascii, data)
    filtered_data = filtered_data.lower()
    return filtered_data
```

How should I modify onlyascii() to leave spaces and periods? I imagine it's not too complicated but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks (sincerely) for the clarification John. I understood that spaces and periods are ASCII characters. However, I was removing both of them unintentionally while trying to remove only non-ASCII characters. I see how my question might have implied otherwise.

Comment: @PoliticalEconomist: Your problem is still very under-specified. See my answer.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

You can filter all characters from the string that are not printable using [string.printable](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.printable), like this:

```
>>> s = "some\x00string. with\x15 funny characters"
>>> import string
>>> printable = set(string.printable)
>>> filter(lambda x: x in printable, s)
'somestring. with funny characters'
```

string.printable on my machine contains:

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c
```

EDIT: On Python 3, filter will return an iterable. The correct way to obtain a string back would be:

```
''.join(filter(lambda x: x in printable, s))
```

Comment: `chr(127) in string.printable` ?

Comment: what's up with those printable chars that are below ordinal 48 ?

Comment: chr(127) in string.printable == False

Comment: Do you mean 0b and 0c? They are part of string.whitespace.

Comment: yes, and from the OP: `if ord(char) < 48 or ord(char) > 127`. About my second comment, I am refering to '*' ,'(', and other printable which are eliminated by the OP...

Comment: Yeah, I was extrapolating that the OP probably meant all printable characters, rather than what was actually said, but might not be the case.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now. Sorry for the confusion - jterrace correctly  interpreted my question.

Comment: this is also great for just filtering to digits - filter(lambda x: x in string.digits, s)

Comment: This is incredibly slow in a large file.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Xodarap777 create a `set(string.printable)` and re-use it for the filtering. Also don't filter the whole file at once - do it in chunks of 8K-512K

Comment: The only problem with using `filter` is that it returns an iterable. If you need a string back (as I did because I needed this when doing list compression) then do this: `''.join(filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, s)`.

Comment: @cjbarth - comment is python 3 specific, but very useful. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use regular expression:  `re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', your-non-ascii-string)` . See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/20079244/658497

Comment: This is the most compatible way of doing the OP's task, I tested in from Python 2.6 to Python 3.5.

Comment: @NoamManos this was 4-5 times faster for me thatn the join...filter...lambda solution, thanks.

Comment: I suspect changing `lambda x: x in printable` to `printable.__contains__` would make it run faster; the `lambda` means more Python level code execution, while directly passing the built-in membership test method removes per character byte code execution.

Comment: [PyLint Complains](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0141) on the use of `filter` when using the above code.  Given that [list comprehensions seem to be preferred](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3013686/1448678) would using `''.join(x for x in s if x in printable)` be a) equivalent, and b) any better?

Comment: Edit: I realise the above is a generator expression, but does the same apply?

Comment: @Jonny - it's most likely equivalent, but I'd have to profile it to know for sure

Comment: @Jonny, The result is the same, time differs (you need to compare if it happens to be a bottleneck). This is easier for an eye - the less the diversity of tools, the faster is reading comprehension. You may want to add an [Enter] before `if` and indent the second line so `if` starts just after `(` from the first line.

Comment: Am I the only one who this doesn't work for? Why wouldnt those characters be included in the printable list? like `0` or `x` for example?

Comment: @CharlesSmith - those are escape sequences

Comment: when assigning value to a variable it works fine whereas reading from file has no effect on filtering.. Dont know why? any ideas?

Answer (score 119):

An easy way to change to a different codec, is by using encode() or decode(). In your case, you want to convert to ASCII and ignore all symbols that are not supported. For example, the Swedish letter å is not an ASCII character:

```
    >>>s = u'Good bye in Swedish is Hej d\xe5'
    >>>s = s.encode('ascii',errors='ignore')
    >>>print s
    Good bye in Swedish is Hej d
```

**Edit:**

Python3: str -> bytes -> str

```
>>>"Hej då".encode("ascii", errors="ignore").decode()
'hej d'
```

Python2: unicode -> str -> unicode

```
>>> u"hej då".encode("ascii", errors="ignore").decode()
u'hej d'
```

Python2: str -> unicode -> str  (decode and encode in reverse order)

```
>>> "hej d\xe5".decode("ascii", errors="ignore").encode()
'hej d'
```

Comment: I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 27`

Comment: I got that error when I put the actual unicode character in the string via copy paste.  When you specify a string as u'thestring' encode works correctly.

Comment: Works only on Py3, but it's elegant.

Comment: For those who are getting the same error as @Xodarap777 : you should first .decode() the string, and only after that encode. For example `s.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', errors='ignore')`

Answer (score 42):

According to @artfulrobot, this should be faster than filter and lambda:

```
import re
re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', your-non-ascii-string)
```

See more examples here  [Replace non-ASCII characters with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space/20079244#20079244)

Comment: This solution answers OP's stated question, but beware that it won't remove non printable characters that are included in ASCII which I think is what OP intended to ask.

Answer (score 8):

You may use the following code to remove non-English letters:

```
import re
str = "123456790 ABC#%? .(朱惠英)"
result = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', str)
print(result)
```

This will return

> 123456790 ABC#%? .()

Comment: Could you explain more on the regex you used? r'[^\x00-\x7f]'

Comment: You should not assign a variable to `str` because that is a built-in python type.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is ambiguous; the first two sentences taken together imply that you believe that space and "period" are non-ASCII characters. This is incorrect. All chars such that ord(char) <= 127 are ASCII characters. For example, your function excludes these characters !"#$%&\'()*+,-./ but includes several others e.g. []{}.

Please step back, think a bit, and edit your question to tell us what you are trying to do, without mentioning the word ASCII, and why you think that chars such that ord(char) >= 128 are ignorable. Also: which version of Python? What is the encoding of your input data?

Please note that your code reads the whole input file as a single string, and your comment ("great solution") to another answer implies that you don't care about newlines in your data. If your file contains two lines like this:

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
```

the result would be `'this is line 1this is line 2'` ... is that what you really want?

A greater solution would include:

1. a better name for the filter function than `onlyascii`
2. recognition that a filter function merely needs to return a truthy value if the argument is to be retained:

   ```
   def filter_func(char):
       return char == '\n' or 32 <= ord(char) <= 126
   # and later:
   filtered_data = filter(filter_func, data).lower()
   ```

Comment: This answer is very helpful to those of us coming in to ask something similar to the OP, and your proposed answer is helpfully pythonic.  I do, however, find it strange that there isn't a more efficient solution to the problem as you interpreted it (which I often run into) - character by character, this takes a very long time in a very large file.

Answer (score 3):

Working my way through Fluent Python (Ramalho) - highly recommended.
List comprehension one-ish-liners inspired by Chapter 2:

```
onlyascii = ''.join([s for s in data if ord(s) < 127])
onlymatch = ''.join([s for s in data if s in
              'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'])
```

Comment: This would not allow for standard ASCII symbols, such as bullet points, degrees symbol,  copyright symbol, Yen symbol, etc.  Also, your first example includes non-printable symbols, such as BELL, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want printable ascii characters you probably should correct your code to:

```
if ord(char) < 32 or ord(char) > 126: return ''
```

this is equivalent, to `string.printable` (answer from @jterrace), except for the absence of returns and tabs ('\t','\n','\x0b','\x0c' and '\r') but doesnt correspond to the range on your question

Comment: Slightly simpler: lambda x: 32 <= ord(x) <= 126

Comment: that's not the same as string.printable because it leaves out string.whitespace, although that might be what the OP wants, depends on things like \n and \t.

Comment: @jterrace right, includes space (ord 32) but no returns and tabs

Comment: yeah, just commenting on "this is equivalent to string.printable", but not true

Comment: I edited the answer, thanks! the OP question is misleading if you do not read it carefully.

Answer (score -1):

this is best way to get ascii characters and clean code, Checks for all possible errors

```
from string import printable

def getOnlyCharacters(texts):
    _type = None
    result = ''
    
    if type(texts).__name__ == 'bytes':
        _type = 'bytes'
        texts = texts.decode('utf-8','ignore')
    else:
        _type = 'str'
        texts = bytes(texts, 'utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore')

    texts = str(texts)
    for text in texts:
        if text in printable:
            result += text
            
    if _type == 'bytes':
        result = result.encode('utf-8')

    return result

text = '�Ahm�����ed Sheri��'
result = getOnlyCharacters(text)

print(result)
#input --> �Ahm�����ed Sheri��
#output --> Ahmed Sheri
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).