# Detect strings with non English characters in Python

Tags: python, regex, non-english

I have some strings that have a mix of English and none English letters. For example:

```
w='_1991_اف_جي2'
```

How can I recognize these types of string using Regex or any other fast method in Python?

I prefer not to compare letters of the string one by one with a list of letters, but to do this in one shot and quickly.

Comment: maybe use the ascii range since ascii os only english characters in the range of 0-255 i believe

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this in Python?

Comment: @TJ1 Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Checkout [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8689826/378704). Don't forget to upvote that answer and the question :)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can just check whether the string can be encoded only with ASCII characters (which are Latin alphabet + some other characters). If it can not be encoded, then it has the characters from some other alphabet.

Note the comment `# -*- coding: ....`. It should be there at the top of the python file (otherwise you would receive some error about encoding)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def isEnglish(s):
    try:
        s.encode(encoding='utf-8').decode('ascii')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

assert not isEnglish('slabiky, ale liší se podle významu')
assert isEnglish('English')
assert not isEnglish('ގެ ފުރަތަމަ ދެ އަކުރު ކަ')
assert not isEnglish('how about this one : 通 asfަ')
assert isEnglish('?fd4))45s&')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In Python 3 what you said was not working correctly, buy I used what you suggested and replaced `s.decode('ascii')` with `s.encode('ascii') and also `UnicodeDecodeError` with `UnicodeEnecodeError` and then it worked.

Comment: I was indeed using Python2 to test my code. Thanks for improving the solution for python3

Comment: I edited this answer to work with both python 2 and 3.

Comment: @TJ1, your approach is correct for Python3, you just have a typo - it's ```UnicodeEncodeError```

Answer (score 48):

IMHO it is the simpliest solution:

```
def isEnglish(s):
  return s.isascii()

print(isEnglish("Test"))
print(isEnglish("_1991_اف_جي2"))

Output:
True
False
```

Comment: `isascii` was introduced in python 3.7. so minimum requirement to use this function you must have >= python 3.7

Answer (score 22):

If you work with strings (not unicode objects), you can clean it with translation and check with `isalnum()`, which is better than to throw Exceptions:

```
import string

def isEnglish(s):
    return s.translate(None, string.punctuation).isalnum()


print isEnglish('slabiky, ale liší se podle významu')
print isEnglish('English')
print isEnglish('ގެ ފުރަތަމަ ދެ އަކުރު ކަ')
print isEnglish('how about this one : 通 asfަ')
print isEnglish('?fd4))45s&')
print isEnglish('Текст на русском')

> False
> True
> False
> False
> True
> False
```

Also you can filter non-ascii characters from string with this function:

```
ascii = set(string.printable)   

def remove_non_ascii(s):
    return filter(lambda x: x in ascii, s)


remove_non_ascii('slabiky, ale liší se podle významu')
> slabiky, ale li se podle vznamu
```

Comment: Hi, while this solution looks nice (I would like to avoid exceptions whenever it is possible), it does not recognize all english characters. Even `Space` is not recognized.

Answer (score 9):

I believe this one would have a minimal runtime since it stops once it finds a character which is not a latin letter. It also uses a generator for better memory usage.

```
import string

def has_only_latin_letters(name):
    char_set = string.ascii_letters
    return all((True if x in char_set else False for x in name))

>>> has_only_latin_letters('_1991_اف_جي2')
False
>>> has_only_latin_letters('bla bla')
True
>>> has_only_latin_letters('blä blä')
False
>>> has_only_latin_letters('저주중앙초등학교')
False
>>> has_only_latin_letters('also a string with numbers and punctuation 1, 2, 4')
True
```

You can also use a different set of characters:

```
>>> string.ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

>>> string.ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

>>> string.digits
'0123456789'

>>> string.digits + string.lowercase
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'    

>>> string.printable
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%& 
\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
```

To add latin accented letters, you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633310/8772634).

Answer (score 6):

```
import re

english_check = re.compile(r'[a-z]')

if english_check.match(w):
    print "english",w
else:
    print "other:",w
```

Comment: What about words like `naïve` or `cliché`?

Comment: Contrary to the accepted answer this also works for strings with accents :-) (I tested with ['tele', 'tèle', 'τήλε'] and the results are [True, True, False].)

Answer (score 0):

```
w.isidentifier()
```

You can easily see the method in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isidentifier):

Return true if the string is a valid identifier according to the language definition, section Identifiers and keywords.

Comment: does not work:
>>> w = '지난해'
>>> w.isidentifier()
True