# How to check if string is 100% ascii in python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, ascii, encode

i have two strings

```
eng = "Clash of Clans – Android Apps on Google Play"
rus = "Castle Clash: Новая Эра - Android Apps on Google Play"
```

and now i want to check whether string is in English or not by using `Python 3`.

I have read this Stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27084708/4108070) and it does not help me as its for `Python 2.x` solution but in comments some one mention that use

```
string.encode('ascii')
```

to make it work in `Python 3.x` but my problem is, in both cases it raises same `UnicodeEncodeError` exception!

Screenshot:
[image]

so now i am stuck here and cant figure out how to make it work!
kindly guide me or i have to use another method to determine if `String` is in `English` or not!
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

As with Salvador Dali's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27084708/3223917) you linked to, you must use a try-catch block to check for an error in encoding.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def isEnglish(s):
    try:
        s.encode('ascii')
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Just to note though, when I copy and pasted your `eng` and `rus` strings to try them, they both came up as `False`. Retyping the English one returned `True`, so I'm not sure what's up with that.

Comment: what do u mean by retyping??

Comment: @maq it means typing the string in rather than using copy/paste. An English keyboard only has ASCII symbols on it so you won't accidentally get the EN DASH that your string contains.

Answer (score 3):

Your English string really isn't true ASCII, it contains the character [`U+2013` - EN DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). This looks very similar to the ASCII dash `U+002d` but it is different.

If this is the only character you need to worry about, you can do a simple replacement to make it work:

```
>>> eng.replace('\u2013', '-').encode('ascii')
b'Clash of Clans - Android Apps on Google Play'
```

Comment: ohhh @Mark Ransom but my main target is to achieve if string is in english or not how can i achieve this??

Comment: @maq use a combination of this answer and Hayley's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the isascii() method:

```
>>> rus.isascii()
False
```

Comment: New in python 3.7 - not before