# How to remove or filter non-english (chinese, korean, japanese, arabic) strings in list?

Tags: python, string, non-english

Here is an input example:

```
['ARTA Travel Group', 'Arta | آرتا', 'ARTAS™ Practice Development',    'ArtBinder', 'Arte Arac Takip App', 'アート建築', 'Arte Brasil Bar &    Grill', 'ArtPod Stage', 'Artpollo扫码', 'Artpollo阿波罗-价值最优的艺术品投资电商',    '아트홀']
```

Like above list, I want to remove elements with CHINESE, KOREAN, JAPANESE, ARBIC.

And below is the expected output (english only):

```
['ARTA Travel Group', 'ARTAS™ Practice Development', 'ArtBinder', 'Arte Arac Takip App', 'Arte Brasil Bar & Grill', 'ArtPod Stage']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regex` and search with unicode range. ™ belongs to [Letterlike Symbols](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/letterlike-symbols/) which ranges from `2100—214F`; you can either include them all or just pick the specific ones.

```
import re

s = ['ARTA Travel Group', 'Arta | آرتا', 'ARTAS™ Practice Development', 'ArtBinder', 'Arte Arac Takip App', 'アート建築', 'Arte Brasil Bar & Grill', 'ArtPod Stage', 'Artpollo扫码', 'Artpollo阿波罗-价值最优的艺术品投资电商', '아트홀']

result = [i for i in s if not re.findall("[^\u0000-\u05C0\u2100-\u214F]+",i)]

print (result)

['ARTA Travel Group', 'ARTAS™ Practice Development', 'ArtBinder', 'Arte Arac Takip App', 'Arte Brasil Bar & Grill', 'ArtPod Stage']
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I can't comment on this post due to the reputation lock but here.

That question is answered here [Detect strings with non English characters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084617/detect-strings-with-non-english-characters-in-python)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can remove non-english strings in the list using the function **isascii** which was introduced in python 3.7. So the minimum requirement to use this function is that you must have the python version >= python 3.7.

```
 def isEnglish(s):

  return s.isascii()

print(isEnglish("Test"))

print(isEnglish("['ARTA Travel Group', 'Arta | آرتا', 'ARTAS™ Practice Development',    'ArtBinder', 'Arte Arac Takip App', 'アート建築', 'Arte Brasil Bar &    Grill', 'ArtPod Stage', 'Artpollo扫码', 'Artpollo阿波罗-价值最优的艺术品投资电商',    '아트홀']"))
```

Output:

```
  ['ARTA Travel Group', 'ARTAS™ Practice Development', 'ArtBinder', 'Arte Arac Takip App', 'Arte Brasil Bar & Grill', 'ArtPod Stage']
```

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression. Put the chars need to the regular expression

```
c = ["ab cde", "test", "张三"]
b = filter(lambda x: re.search("[a-zA-Z\s]+",x) is not None, c)
```

just give an idea to you.

Comment: Yes, this is not the direct answer to the question, this is just give an idea, special chars need to added to the regular expression, "&" should not work also.