# GitPython - Repo.clone results in TypeError: execve() arg 2 must contain only strings

Tags: python, gitpython

I'm executing the following GitPython related code to clone from a remote repository. The remote repo url is usually of format `https://username:password@host/path/to/repo.git`.

```
Repo.clone_from(repo_url, local_repo_path)
```

This results in the following error, which is not really helpful

```
 File "clone.py", line 192, in clone
    Repo.clone_from(repo_url,local_repo_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/repo/base.py", line 844, in clone_from
    return cls._clone(Git(os.getcwd()), url, to_path, GitCmdObjectDB, progress, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/repo/base.py", line 791, in _clone
    v=True, **add_progress(kwargs, git, progress))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 431, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 802, in _call_process
    return self.execute(make_call(), **_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 556, in execute
    **subprocess_kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execve() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

I've tried encoding the values as utf-8, with no luck. The type of these variables are shown as `str` when logged just before clone command.

```
Repo.clone_from(unicode(repo_url, "utf-8"), unicode(local_repo_path, "utf-8"))
```

Comment: Which version of GitPython are you using ? Did you try it with version v0.3.6, which is the latest one ? You can see which version you have using `import git; print(git.__version__)`.

Comment: Thanks @Byron for the tips. Yes I'm using the latest, released in Jan 2015. I found what was wrong. I'm decrypting the password I get before inserting it to the repo url, and Pycrypto had inserted (as far as I understand, padded with) non-printable characters at the end of the decrypted password. This was the root cause of the issue. I was able to fix this with the help of this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689795/python-remove-non-ascii-characters-but-leave-periods-and-spaces

Answer (score 1):

I believe it could be that your current working directory contains unicode characters, or is returned as unicode by `os.getcwd()`, which is used [by gitpython when handling `clone_from`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/master/git/repo/base.py#L849).

As the latest version of GitPython definitely handle encodings and unicode, I suspect you are not using the latest version of GitPython (v0.3.6). If you do, [please file a bug](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. I'm decrypting the password I get before inserting it to the repo url, and Pycrypto had inserted (as far as I understand, padded with) non-printable characters at the end of the decrypted password. This was the root cause of the issue. I was able to fix this with the help of the following.

[How can I remove non-ASCII characters but leave periods and spaces using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689795/python-remove-non-ascii-characters-but-leave-periods-and-spaces)