# How does filtering work in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python has filter method which filters the desired output on some criteria as like in the following example.

```
>>> s = "some\x00string. with\x15 funny characters"
>>> import string
>>> printable = set(string.printable)
>>> filter(lambda x: x in printable, s)
'somestring. with funny characters'
```

The example is taken from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689795/how-can-i-remove-non-ascii-characters-but-leave-periods-and-spaces-using-python). Now, when I am trying to do similar thing in Python IDE it does return the result `'somestring. with funny characters'` infact it return this `<filter object at 0x0000020E1792EC50>`. In IDE I cannot use just simple Enter so I am running this whole code with a print when filtering. Where I am doing it wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python3 filter returns a generator (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#filter))

You therefore normally want to convert this into a list to view its contents, or in your case, a string:

```
>>> s = "some\x00string. with\x15 funny characters"
>>> import string
>>> printable = set(string.printable)
>>> f = filter(lambda x: x in printable, s)
>>> ''.join(f)
'somestring. with funny characters'
```

The benefit of `filter` being an iterator, is that it uses much less memory. It can also easily be looped over, just like a list.

Answer (score 2):

In python 2.x filter returns a new list but on python 3.x it returns a filter object (generator), if you would like to see the results just call `list(yourobject)` for transform it into a list.

You must know that the python 3 version (as a generator) works [lazily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), alternatively you can use the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module for keep the behaviour on python 2 similar to python 3.

```
>>> list(itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x > 5, xrange(20)))
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: Actually in python2 `filter` special cases strings! Otherwise the result of `filter(lambda x: True, "abc")` would be `['a', 'b', 'c']` but actually is `abc`.

Comment: To be correct, filter in Python 2 returns can return either a list, a tuple or a string.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid  That's not true. It special cases `tuple` and `str`. but for example `filter(lambda x: True, {1,2,3}) == [1,2,3]` so `set`s are converted to `list`s. Also if you have a `namedtuple` it will be converted to a plain `tuple` etc.