# Strange char that appears on Python console but not on win file name

Tags: python, python-2.7, ascii

I wrote a simple script to rename a bunch of files in a directory:

```
import os

crash_course_dir = ...
os.chdir(crash_course_dir)

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    dot_idx = filename.index('.')
    new_file_name = filename[:dot_idx].strip() + ' . ' + filename[dot_idx + 1:].strip()
    print 'before:\t', filename, '\nafter:\t', new_file_name, '\n\n'
    os.rename(filename, new_file_name)
```

and it works as I expected except for one thing:

```
after:  7 . �2,000 Years of Chinese History! The Mandate of Heaven and Confucius - World History.mp4
```

This was the output in my console, but when I look inside the directory, all I see is `7 . ‎2,000 Years of Chinese History! The Mandate of Heaven and Confucius - World History.mp4`

This is the only file (out of 42) that shows this weird char (as far as I can see).

---

I added this check:

```
if new_file_name[0] == '7':
    print new_file_name[4], ord(new_file_name[4])
```

**Output:** `� 253`

*Why is this happening? Someone mistakenly added this char and because it's not windows readable, no-one noticed? Leaving this `char` could cause problems? (I can remove it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689826/3512538))*

I use Python 2.7 with Spyder. Windows 8.1

Comment: Actually, I get `ord` as `8206`, or `\u200e` (using Python 3), and the `repr` of the string shows `\xe2\x80\x8e` in Python 2, i.e. seems to be a multi-byte unicode character.

Comment: How could that be?

Comment: @tobias_k You get the numbers, codes and bytes right but linked the wrong page. It is the [Left-To-Right Mark](https://unicode-table.com/200E/).

Comment: @Goyo You are right, I mixed up hex and decimal representation...

Answer (score 0):

Try decoding the file name with `UTF-8` format.

```
print filename.decode('utf-8')
```