# Python3 weird chars and utf-8 can't remove it

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem, I am trying to get a string to be equal in Python3 and in MySQL, the problem is I expect it should be utf-8 but the problem is it's not the same.

I have this string

> station√¶r pc > station√¶r pc

and what I wish now is it should look like this

> stationr pc > stationr pc

and I have tried to use bytes(string, 'utf-8').decode('utf-8') and a lots of other things.

I hope one here can help me to strip all the weird characters out of my strings so I can use it better, the problem is the data coming from external files and I can't control the encoding.

Comment: Shouldn't this actually be "stationær pc"? This looks exactly like mojibake for interpreting UTF-8 data with the Mac Roman codec. I can reproduce it with `'stationær'.encode('utf8').decode('macroman')`.

Comment: In general, there's no need to control the encoding of input data. It's important to *know* what encoding was used, then you can always decode accordingly.

Comment: If you really want to convert "stationær pc" to "stationr pc", you can do `"stationær pc".encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode('ascii')`.

Comment: thanks yeah its working this way, need to ignore it by using bytes(cat['Title'],'utf-8').decode('utf8').encode('ascii', errors='ignore').strip() thanks a lot :) will you make a anwser?

Comment: I'm sure there are dozens of duplicates of this question, no need for another duplicate answer. Searching for "python remove non-ascii characters", I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18430817/1698431), for example.

Comment: Btw, `bytes(x, 'utf8').decode('utf8') == x` for any x, so you can skip that.

Answer (score 0):

As lenz found out, you have "Mojibake" with `CHARACTER SET macroman` versus utf8.

See [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for ways that Mojibake can happen.  (It reads "latin1" instead of "macroman".)