# removing Chinese in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I am trying to remove all chinese characters from csv, that contains both latin and chinese characters. Data looks like:

```
    address                                                 lat
1   农工商超市, Zhangjiang, Pudong New District, 203718       31.204024
2   欧尚, 3057号, Jinke Road, Pudong, 201203, China          31.181804
```

I need it to look like:

```
    address                                                 lat
1   , Zhangjiang, Pudong New District, 203718               31.204024
2   , 3057, Jinke Road, Pudong, 201203, China               31.181804
```

I tried with `df.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "")` and `df.replace(/[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]/gu,"")` but I get error:

```
    df1.replace([^\x00-\x7F],"");
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

need help! thanks

Comment: It seems like you forgot the string literal delimiters...

Comment: Why are you using Javascript syntax regex?

Comment: I swear I read the topic title as "Removing Chinese pandas"...

Answer (score 6):

you were almost there:

```
df['address'] = df['address'].str.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '')
```

result:

```
In [99]: df
Out[99]:
                                     address        lat
0  , Zhangjiang, Pudong New District, 203718  31.204024
1  , 3057, Jinke Road, Pudong, 201203, China  31.181804
```

Answer (score 3):

One way may also be to use `filter` with `string.printable` as similar to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689826/5916727):

```
import string
printable = set(string.printable)
df['address'] = df['address'].apply(lambda row: ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in printable, row)))
df
```

Result:

```
                                    address        lat
1  , Zhangjiang, Pudong New District, 203718  31.204024
2  , 3057, Jinke Road, Pudong, 201203, China  31.181804
```

Or using `encode` and `decode` with `lambda` as similar to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18430817/5916727)

```
df['address'] = df['address'].apply(lambda row: row.encode('ascii',errors='ignore').decode())
```

Answer (score 1):

An arguably more robust way of doing this if you wanted to limit your character set is to read in a file object with the encoding that you want while ignoring errors

```
with open('your_csv_file.csv', encoding='ascii', errors='ignore') as infile:
    df = pd.read_csv(infile)
```