# Remove utf-8 literals in a string python

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, hex

I'm new to python,I have a string like:

```
s= 'HDCF\xc3\x82\xc2\xae FTAE\xc3\x82\xc2\xae Greater China'
```

I want to remove all the unicode literals in a string like:

```
'\xc3\x82\xc2\xae'
```

I need output like:

```
'HDFC FTAE Greater China'
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Python 2 and Python 3 differ in syntax for strings.  An accurate answer needs to know if `s` is a Python 2 byte string or a Python 3 Unicode string.

Comment: It looks like your data is [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).  What you have is `'HDCF® FTAE® Greater China'` double-encoded as UTF-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Python 2 (default string type is bytes):

```
>>> s = 'HDCF\xc3\x82\xc2\xae FTAE\xc3\x82\xc2\xae Greater China'
>>> s.decode('ascii',errors='ignore').encode('ascii')
'HDCF FTAE Greater China'
```

On Python 3 (default string type is Unicode):

```
>>> s = 'HDCF\xc3\x82\xc2\xae FTAE\xc3\x82\xc2\xae Greater China'
>>> s.encode('ascii',errors='ignore').decode('ascii')
'HDCF FTAE Greater China'
```

Note that the original string is a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).  Ideally fix how the string was read, but you can undo the damage with (Python 3):

```
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'HDCF® FTAE® Greater China'
```

The original string was double-encoded as UTF-8.  This works by converting the string directly 1:1 back to bytes<sup>1</sup>, decoding as UTF-8, then converting directly back to bytes again and decoding with UTF-8 again.

Here's the Python 2 version:

```
>>> s = 'HDCF\xc3\x82\xc2\xae FTAE\xc3\x82\xc2\xae Greater China'
>>> print s.decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
HDCF® FTAE® Greater China
```

<sup>1</sup>This works because the `latin1` codec is a 256-byte encoding and directly maps to the first 256 Unicode codepoints.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to limit the string to ASCII-compatible characters, you can encode it into ASCII and ignore unencodable characters, and then decode it again:

```
x = 'HDCF\xc3\x82\xc2\xae FTAE\xc3\x82\xc2\xae Greater China'
print(x.encode("ascii", "ignore").decode("utf-8"))
```

produces `HDCF FTAE Greater China`.

Check out [str.encode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) and [bytes.decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)

Comment: thanks for reply,it's showing like Error:UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Works on Python 3.6 with the input you supplied

Comment: Yeah indeed, I didn't test it with the indentation posted here. Fixed it by putting it on two separate lines

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your string using the [`string.printable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#string.printable) function to check whether your characters can be printed:

```
import string

s= 'HDCF\xc3\x82\xc2\xae FTAE\xc3\x82\xc2\xae Greater China'

printable = set(string.printable)
s = "".join(filter(lambda c: c in printable, s))
print(s)
```

Output:

```
HDCF FTAE Greater China
```

Reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689795/how-can-i-remove-non-ascii-characters-but-leave-periods-and-spaces-using-python#8689826) question.

Answer (score 0):

May be this help,

```
s = 'HDCF\xc3\x82\xc2\xae FTAE\xc3\x82\xc2\xae Greater China'
d = ''.join([i for i in s if ord(i) < 127])
print(d)
# OUTPUT as: HDCF FTAE Greater China
```