# python json.dumps adds symbols at start and end of string <14> and \x00

Tags: python, logging, fluentd

My problem: I try to send logs from python3 project via `logging` module to fluentd.

```
log = '{"@timestamp":"2020-06-18T11:52:37.391","severity":"INFO", "message":"Processing request started"}'
logging.error(json.dumps(log))
```

At fluentd I get such error:

```
pattern not matched data="<14>{"@timestamp":"2020-06-18T11:52:37.391","severity":"INFO", "message":"Processing request started"}\x00"
```

I see strange symbols, `<14>` and `\x00`. When I try to send same string via bash console --everything works well

```
echo -n '{"@timestamp":"2020-06-18T11:52:37.391","severity":"INFO", "message":"Processing request started"}' > /dev/udp/HOST/PORT
```

Looks like there are some problems with encoding, but I can't recognise how to fix this error in python.

Comment: Have you tried removing non-printable characters from the string?

Comment: yes, tried via .replace method after `json.dumps()`, nothing changed

Comment: What about trying this approach for removing them? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689826

Comment: [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) encodes *a python data structure* into a json string. If you encode a string it still works, it escapes all the quotes