# Removing special & invalid characters from string

Tags: python, regex

I have this string:

```
irak|"iraq"|"Ø²Ù„Ø²Ø§Ù„ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø§Ù‚"|"Ø²Ù„Ø²Ø§Ù„ Ø§ÙŠØ±Ø§Ù†"|"Ù‡Ø²Ø© Ø§Ø±Ø¶ÙŠØ©"|"Ù‡Ø²Ø© Ø§Ø±Ø¶ÙŠØ© Ø§ÙŠØ±Ø§Ù†"|"Ø²Ù„Ø²Ù„Ù‡"|"Ø²Ù„Ø²Ù„Ù‡ Ø§ÙŠØ±Ø§Ù†"|"Ø²Ù…ÙŠÙ† Ù„Ø±Ø²Ù‡ Ø§ÙŠØ±Ø§Ù†"|"iran news"|"iran quake"|"earthquake"|"Iran-Iraq border earthquake"
```

And the thing I want is to remove all the characters except English alphabets and numbers. Like for above string the result should be:

```
irak|iraq|iran news|iran quake|earthquake|Iran-Iraq border earthquake
```

And this should be done using regex in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove non-ASCII characters but leave periods and spaces using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689795/how-can-i-remove-non-ascii-characters-but-leave-periods-and-spaces-using-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a way to do that in two steps:

```
s1 = re.sub(r'\|[^a-zA-Z]+\|', "|", s)
s2 = re.sub(r'"', "", s1)
```

The output (s2) is:

```
irak|iraq|iran news|iran quake|earthquake|Iran-Iraq border earthquake
```