# Python not picking up UTF-8 encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having some trouble encoding ascii characters to UTF-8, or a string is not picking up the encoding.

```
import unicodecsv as csv
import re
import pyodbc
import sys
import unicodedata
    
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
    
def remove_non_ascii_1(text):

    text.encode('utf-8')
    
    for i in text:

        return ''.join(i for i in text if i=='£')
```

In Python 2.7 I get the error

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file on line 16, but no encoding declared; see SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file.
```

With the Unicode replacement

```
return ''.join(i for i in text if i=='\xc2')
```

the error is

```
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

Sample text :

row from a csv file reading in

```
[u'06/11/2020', u'ABC', u'32154E', u'3214', u'DEF', u'Cash Purchase', u'Final', u'', u'20.00%', u'ABC', u'Sold From Pickup', u'New ', u'10.00%', u'0', u'15%', u'\xa3469.84', u'Jonathan Jerome', u'3', u'\xa3140.95', u'2%', u'\xa393.97', u'\xa39,396.83', u'', u'\xa35,638.00', u'30/06/2020', u'4', u'Boiler-Amended']
```

I want to remove the \xa3 or £ in the currency fields.

Comment: Can you add a sample text containing issues?

Comment: `text.encode('utf-8')` does nothing in your code, you have to store the result.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7? If yes, do you really have to? Management of Unicode has been one the the great improvements in Python 3...

Answer (score 1):

First 2 things ahead:

1. Don't use Python 2 any more because of reason mentioned [here](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)!
2. Don't use different encodings in Python 2.
   **TL;DR** Python 3 just improved so many things regarding encodings that it simply isn't worth it.
   **Whole story:** read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35444608/9346708)

Ok this out of the way let's start fixing your code.

As [Klaus D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d) already mentioned you do not save the result of text. This leads to an encoding warning when comparing seamingly equal characters (£ and £) but one is encoded in the encoding coming from the file you read the other one is encoded in ascii (despite you encoding your code in `-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-`. This is just to show what your code-file is encoded in, this does not change the behaviour of the interpreter regarding str-parsing).
*Edit:* Also when comparing to the character you will need to compare to a unicode char so you could either convert it or simply tell the interpreter to encode it as unicode in the first place (that's why I added a leading 'u' in front of your '£')

To fix this simply safe your result into `text` again after you called `text.encode('utf-8')`.

Additionally the "shebang" and the encoding info should always be on the very top of a file that as soon as you open the file you know what you are dealing with.

Something else I would correct is the first `for`-loop. this one is unnecessary because you return out of this function anyway after you handled the first element.

This means the completely "corrected" code is this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import unicodecsv as csv
import re
import pyodbc
import sys
import unicodedata

def remove_non_ascii_1(text):
    text.encode('utf-8')
    return ''.join(i for i in text if i==u'£')
```

**PS:** You should really think again about whether the `def remove_non_ascii_1(text)` is really necessary. By the looks of it you already input a list of unicode encoded strings which you probably directly read from the file. This means you don't need to correct encoding though the comparison for '£' could stay. You might just want to rename the method ;)

Hope this helped and fixed possible unclarities about Python 2 encodings :D

If you print your list as a whole now you will see it still contains \xca and not the actual '£' but if you print the elements seperately it works fine. This is because the `__str__()` method of list does not encode unicodes directly but uses the standard ascii encoding...

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 greatly improved unicode text handling. If you have to use Python 2.7, I would recommend using the `codecs` library when reading text files since it helps you with Pyhton 2.7 unicode issues:

```
import codecs
fp = codecs.open("file", "r"; encoding="utf-8")
```

In your case I noticed that you are using unicodecsv as a drop-in csv replacement. In this case, you can hand the parameter `encoding="utf-8"` when reading the csv file into a list:

```
r = csv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8')
```

For just removing non-Ascii characters I would recommend checking [this good answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689826/1331407)