# How to get a name with random prefixes and suffixes

Tags: python

I have a semi unique problem and I have no clue where to start. I'm using python

So im trying to get a bunch of info about items off two API's and these API uses two different id methods

Name and ID

The Name will look something like: Helmet of Divan

The ID will look like: DIVAN_HELMET

This is easy for me connect the two in a dictionary. My problem is sometimes the names will have suffixes and prefixs. Such as:

`Wise Helmet of Divan` or `Clean Helmet of Divan` or even have Unicode like `✪ Helmet of Divan ✪`.

I want to get the ID DIVAN_HELMET from these names, but I can't know how many characters the prefix is or even if there is a suffix/prefix. I need to do this in mass for over 3 thousand items with dozens of suffixes and prefixes.

Comment: I have no idea what "semi unique" means. Something is either unique or it isn't. Also, you forgot to post the code you're struggling with https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If the base name is always present, then you can use a loop with `if looking_for in new_name:`.  It's going to take time

Comment: `"Helmet of Divan" in "Wise Helmet of Divan"` will return you true if first is part of second. Is it solves your problem?

Comment: Have you tried regex? It will be better if you share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to get such output: `DIVAN_HELMET`

From such inputs: `Wise Helmet of Divan` or `Clean Helmet of Divan` or `✪ Helmet of Divan ✪`

First you can remove all non-ASCII characters, e.g. like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689826/3706717) :

```py
import string
printable = set(string.printable)
str_input = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in printable, str_input))
```

Then you need to convert them to all lowercase like `str_input = str_input.lower()`

Then, you need to [tokenize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization) the input; the easiest way is just to split it by space, e.g.: `arr_str_input = str_input.split(" ")`

Then you need to remove the [stopwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_word) like 'of' or 'the'. For this step you can use publicly available stopword list like [this](https://github.com/stopwords-iso/stopwords-en/blob/master/stopwords-en.txt) or just hardcode removal of word 'of' if that's all the stopword in your input text. e.g.: `arr_str_input.remove("of")`

Then you need to remove the prefix or suffix. In this step you can just supply the list of all prefix/suffix yourself or use readily made one like [this](https://github.com/Rayraegah/adjectives) (be careful since it can be very big list)

After all that, you should have a list/array of only 2 word like `['helmet','divan']`. Last step should be just arranging them and making them uppercase, e.g.:

```
result = ['helmet','divan']
result.reverse()
print('_'.join(result).upper())
# outputs DIVAN_HELMET
```