# Removing string extra characters via python string functions

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here is the web CSS from which I want to extract the Location information.

```
<div class="location">
    <div class="listing-location">Location</div>
    <div class="location-areas">
    <span class="location">Al Bayan</span>
    ‪,‪
    <span class="location">Nepal</span>
    </div>
    <div class="area-description"> 3.3 km from Mall of the Emirates </div>
    </div>
```

Python Beautuifulsoup4 Code I used is:

```
   try:
            title= soup.find('span',{'id':'listing-title-wrap'})
            title_result= str(title.get_text().strip())
            print "Title: ",title_result
    except StandardError as e:
            title_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
            print title_result
```

**Output:**

```
"Al Bayanأ¢â‚¬آھ,أ¢â‚¬آھ

                            Nepal"
```

How can I convert the format into the following

```
['Al Bayan', 'Nepal']
```

What should be the line second of the code to get this output

Comment: What is the HTML that produces this output?

Comment: Are they all in that format? Some jbberish and then 2 line breaks then the real text?

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/2743163/524743

Comment: @LutzHorn its a beautifulsoup4 (python)

Comment: Posting some more code might actually help.

Comment: @Keatinge yes .. its a constant format. perhaps there is some function to remove this unwanted text and spaces

Comment: @Panetta I'm pretty sure you're doing this all wrong, are you using the same HTML as from your other identical question yesterday? If you are I will show you a much easier way

Comment: Consider `a` as ur string. `[i.replace("  ","") for i in filter(None,(a.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore')).split('\n'))]`

Comment: @WannaBeCoder i updated the question

Comment: @Keatinge yes its the same code. I couldnt get the answer there. All I want is to convert the output into proper format. Its more of a python string problem

Comment: @Panetta no it's not a python string problem. Just use an html parser like BeautifulSoup and it's 100x easier. Look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading it wrong, just the read the spans with class location

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
locList = [loc.text for loc in soup.find_all("span", {"class" : "location"})]
print(locList)
```

This prints exactly what you wanted:

```
['Al Bayan', 'Nepal']
```

Comment: [u'Al Bayan', 'u'Nepal]  This is the output.

Comment: map with string. That will give your expected result. `map(str,output_list)`

Comment: @Panetta I've changed it slightly, run it now. There's no reason to use a map when there's already a list comp anyway

Comment: @Keatinge You are right. I just suggested an alternative option.

Comment: @Panetta: do not call `str()` on Unicode strings—it breaks as soon as you get a non-ascii character in it. Format the list manually if you don't like:  
`[u'Al Bayan', 'u'Nepal] `  text representation e.g., `print("\n".join(locList))` (to print each item on its own line). See [Python string prints as [u'String'\]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36891685/4279)

Answer (score 0):

There is a one line solution. Consider `a` as your string.

```
In [38]: [i.replace("  ","") for i in filter(None,(a.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore')).split('\n'))]
Out[38]: ['Al Bayan,', 'Nepal']
```

Comment: asci codec cant encode character u'\u202a'. Tried it and this was the error

Comment: @Panetta What is your exact error. And what you given as input. It's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp to filter only letter and spaces :

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[A-Za-z ]+', area_result)
['Al Bayan', ' Nepal']
```

Hope it'll be helpful.