# pygame, removing special characters, check encoding for PyDictionary

Tags: python, pydictionary

I am a complete beginner so if the question seems obvious or stupid I apologize beforehand.

Working on an app in PyGame that reads a random word from a file and then searches it's definition using PyDictionary.

The code I started with is as follows;

```
WORD = random.choice(WORDS)
dict = PyDictionary()

meaning = dict.meaning(WORD)
```

the word is printed on screen without issue;

```
word_text = play_again_font.render(f"{WORD.upper()}", True, "#FFB90F")
```

but when I try to call the meaning I get;

```
meaning_text = meaning_font.render(f"{meaning()}", True, "#FFB90F")
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

As I found the PyDictionary was sending the output as dict which is indeed not callable.

So I tried a new approach.

My new code is;
I have a python file with a WORDS list

```
WORD = WORDS
WORD_LIST = list(WORD)
word_n = random.choice(WORD_LIST)
```

I send the random word, defined in the variable word_n, to a txt file:

```
file = open('test.txt', 'wb')
pickle.dump(word_n,file)
file.close()
```

As the word has special characters and white spaces I read, clean and send to another file;

```
def clean_word():
    string = open('test.txt').read().lstrip().strip()
    new_str = ''.join([i for i in string if i.isalpha()]).strip()
    open('mean.txt', 'w').write(new_str)



def get_mean():
    clean = open('mean.txt').readlines()
    dicto = PyDictionary()
    meaning = dicto.meaning(clean)
```

The join function works in as far as it removes white spaces (NUL) and so, but it leaves this character before the word: œ
these characters get removed: €EOT•ENONULNULNULŒSOHo”.

I've tried:

```
new_str = ''.join([i for i in string if i.isalpha()]).strip().replace('œ','')
```

This does not work as the œ symbol remains at the beginning of the word.

I've read that it could be encoding so tried:

```
new_str = ''.join([i for i in string if i.isalpha()]).strip().encode('utf-8')
```

also tried .encode('cp1252') but neither method works.
Tried decode but this doesn't appear to be an option.

Right now I cannot send the word to PyDictionary as it returns "None".

```
meaning_text = meaning_font.render(f"{clean_word()}", True, "#FFB90F")
```

I'm assuming this is due to the symbol in front of the word.

How can I strip everything to be able to pass the variable to PyDictionary?

EDIT

This does not appear to be encoding.

I kept trying and have found that the word does get passed to PyDictionary and that it does produce a definition.

I have tested by;

```
def get_mean():
clean = open('mean.txt').readlines()
dicto = PyDictionary()
meaning = dicto.meaning(clean)
print(meaning)
```

The meaning is indeed shown on Terminal.

Another test I did was:

```
def get_mean():
clean = open('mean.txt').readline()
dicto = PyDictionary()
meaning = dicto.meaning(clean)
file = open('meaners.txt', 'wb')
pickle.dump(meaning, file)
file.close()
```

I can confirm that the file meaners.txt gets created meaning gets sent to it.

Why am I able to pass the variable word_n but not get_mean?

ie.

the below works and renders the word as expected;

play_again_font.render(f"{word_n.upper()}", True, "#FFB90F")

But this does not work:

meaning_text = meaning_font.render(f"{get_mean()}", True, "#FFB90F")

It always returns None even when the definition gets sent to the created file.

If I try to create a variable ie;

```
my_var = get_mean()
```

I get error;

meaning_text = meaning_font.render(f"{my_var()}", True, "#FFB90F")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

if I call the function directly it returns None;

meaning_text = meaning_font.render(f"{get_mean()}", True, "#FFB90F")

Do I need to redirect stdout perhaps?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT;

minimal reproducible example:

I have a words.py file which contains:

```
WORDS = [ "a", "bunch", "of", "words", "bared" ]
```

import random
import pickle
import words
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
import pygame
import pygame.display

```
WORD = words.WORDS
WORD_list = list(WORD)
word_n = random.choice(WORD_list)
file = open('mean.txt', 'wb')
pickle.dump(word_n,file)
file.close()
print(word_n)

def get_mean():
    dicto = PyDictionary()
    meaning = dicto.meaning(word_n)
    print(meaning)
    file = open('meaners.txt', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(meaning, file)
    file.close()

get_mean()
```

test.py"
bared
{'Verb': ['lay bare', 'make public', 'lay bare'], 'Adjective': ['having the head uncovered']}
{'Verb': ['lay bare', 'make public', 'lay bare'], 'Adjective': ['having the head uncovered']}

Process finished with exit code 0

The issue I'm facing is when I try to render text with the get_mean()
The word_n variable is displayed without problems.

```
test_text = play_again_font.render(f"{word_n.upper()}", True, "#FFB90F")
test_rect = test_text.get_rect(center=(WIDTH / 2, 650))
```

The above works and the random word is displayed on screen.

But the below, displaying the get_mean() does not display the definition.

```
meaning_font = pygame.font.SysFont('segoe-ui-symbol.ttf', 20)
meaning_text = meaning_font.render(f"{get_mean()}", True, "#FFB90F")
meaning_rect = meaning_text.get_rect(center=(WIDTH / 2, 200))
```

Comment: You could encode to `ascii`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46704307/2280890)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried but still no go.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to include a [mcve] to make it easier to help you. Also `dict` refers to the built-in python dictionary class, so you shouldn't use it as a variable name.

Comment: thanks import random for the tips and for taking the time to reply. I've added a working example to hopefully show better what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some trouble trying to recreate your problem with [PyDictionary](https://pypi.org/project/PyDictionary/), it's dependent on a [library](https://pypi.org/project/goslate/) for translation that no longer [installs](https://github.com/geekpradd/PyDictionary/issues/52) from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/).

Fortunately a fork is available, [PyMultiDictionary](https://pypi.org/project/PyMultiDictionary/), that installs for me, so I've created a minimal example. You will likely want to handle the processing of the `dictionary.meaning()` function call with more care. If you change the dictionary, then the response format will change. One of your issues seems to be that you're not passing strings to the `font.render()` function.

```
import random
import pygame

from PyMultiDictionary import MultiDictionary
dictionary = MultiDictionary()

def get_meaning(word):
    """Return the first meaning of a word"""
    # strip non-ascii
    word = word.encode('ascii',errors='ignore').decode()
    print(f"  Searching for {word} … ", end="")
    word_type, word_meaning, word_wikipedia = dictionary.meaning("en", word)
    print(f"found {word_meaning}")
    if word_meaning == "":
        word_meaning = "No definition found"
    return word_meaning

def blit_text(surface, text, pos, font, color=pygame.Color('black')):
    """Multi-line text blit from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42015712/2280890"""
    words = [word.split(' ') for word in text.splitlines()]
    # 2D array where each row is a list of words.
    space = font.size(' ')[0]  # The width of a space.
    max_width, max_height = surface.get_size()
    x, y = pos
    for line in words:
        for word in line:
            word_surface = font.render(word, True, color)
            word_width, word_height = word_surface.get_size()
            if x + word_width >= max_width:
                x = pos[0]  # Reset the x.
                y += word_height  # Start on new row.
            surface.blit(word_surface, (x, y))
            x += word_width + space
        x = pos[0]  # Reset the x.
        y += word_height  # Start on new row.


word_list = ["bunch", "Φof", "wordsΩ", "b✖areδ", "!#@$"]

pygame.init()
# grab the first installed font
sys_font = pygame.font.SysFont(pygame.font.get_fonts()[0], 20)

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Random Meanings")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
txt_pos = (60,60)

word = random.choice(word_list)
meaning = get_meaning(word)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                word = random.choice(word_list)
                meaning = get_meaning(word)
    # update state
    txt = f"{word}:\n{meaning}"
    # draw background
    window.fill(pygame.Color("white"))
    # draw text
    blit_text(window, txt, txt_pos, sys_font)
    # update screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
pygame.quit()
```

This will display a window like:

[image: Meaning of bunch]

The simplistic special character removal performed is through conversion to ASCII as suggested in the comment and the multi-line text drawing is from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42015712/2280890).

Comment: Thank you so much. This made me see where I was going wrong. I was passing the get_mean() without referencing the word_n variable.
This def fixed it. Much appreciated.